# Trying to get the username using MODELS but getting this error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, database, model, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

**ERROR:** `ErrorException in 814a6fb85b2cceb262c3a8191c08e42742940fc7.php line 223: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/m/TS/resources/views/d/show-details.blade.php)`

Actually I am trying to get the username who has stored the result in the database i.e. `TN has got user_id as a foreign key in the table` so I need to get the `username` from that `user_id` using `models but I am getting this problem`Trying to get property of non-object`when I try to get the`username` associated with the id. I dont know where I am doing it wrong.

THE ERROR I AM GETTING IS HERE `value="{{$tn->users->username}}"` WHICH SHOWS IN THE CACHED FILE.

I have given my code below too to look.

Thank you in advance

## Controller

```
public function details($id) {

        $d= $this->detail->showDetails($id);
        $tn= TN::find($id);

// calling functions from Model
        $n = $d->tN;
        $o = $d->tO;

return view('details.show-details', compact('d','o', 'n', 'tn'));

}
```

## View

```
foreach($n as $n)
<input style="font-size:10px;font-weight: bold; color:black; background:#59d864;" value="{{$tn->users->username}}" readonly>
```

## Models

### User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\TN;
use App\TO;
use App\UserType;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function tN() {
    return $this->hasMany(TN::class);
}

public function tO() {
    return $this->hasMany(TO::class);
}

public function userType() {
    return $this->belongsTo(UserType::class);
}
```

}

## TO Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\D;
use App\TT;
use App\User;

class TO extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['o', 'date'];

public function d() {
    return $this->belongsTo(D::class);
}

public function tOType() {
    return $this->belongsTo(TOType::class);
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

## TN Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Debtor;
use App\TracingType;
use App\User;

class TN extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['r', 'date'];

public function d() {
   return $this->belongsTo(D::class);
}

public function tType() {
    return $this->belongsTo(TType::class);
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

}
```

Comment: Add ___the complete error message to your question___ please

Comment: `ErrorException in 814a6fb85b2cceb262c3a8191c08e42742940fc7.php line 223: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/m/TS/resources/views/d/show-details.blade.php)`

Comment: The error is in this line `{{$tn->users->username}}` ... I think it's not going into `users` function in the model to fetch the name but when I do `$tn->user_id` it returns me the `id' ...

Comment: `foreach($n as $n)` ___Instant destruction___

Comment: I think I have found it ... I am not getting `d_id` from `TN` table ... right now if you look at this line of code `$tn= TN::find($id);` then it is finding the same `$id` in `TN` table where I need to get `d_id` in `TN` table so that I can fetch out the `username` but still getting problem with fetching the `d_id` from `TN` table ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have sorted this problem but forgot to post it in here the problem was here

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This should be `public function user()` rather than `users`. Because it `belongsTo` to `User` class, it should be singular not plural and for `hasMany` we use plurals. Thank you for your help though ... :)